# I need to be able to select two ID's

Tags: full-text-search, prototypejs

Hello all I need to be able to search by multiple ID block0_b7 and block1_b7. Here is my current code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
var searchString = "Incident",
    pageContent = document.getElementById("block1_b7").innerHTML;
var searchString2 = "Voice Services",
    pageContent = document.getElementById("block1_b7").innerHTML;
var searchString3 = "Data Service EVDO-1X & LTE",
    pageContent = document.getElementById("block1_b7").innerHTML;
if (pageContent.indexOf(searchString) != -1) 
   document.getElementById("areas").style.display = "inline";
if (pageContent.indexOf(searchString2) != -1) 
   document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display = "inline";
if (pageContent.indexOf(searchString3) != -1) 
   document.getElementById("dropdown2").style.display = "inline";
}
</script>  <script type="text/javascript">
    var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
    var mydropdown2 = document.getElementById('dropdown2');
 var myareas = document.getElementById('areas');
    mydropdown.onchange = function(){
         comment_body.value = comment_body.value +'\n'+ this.value;
  var f = document.forms[2].submit();
           f.submit();
    }
 mydropdown2.onchange = function(){
        comment_body.value = comment_body.value +'\n'+ this.value;
  var f = document.forms[2].submit();
           f.submit();
    }
 myareas.onchange = function(){ 
        comment_body.value = comment_body.value +'\n'+ this.value;
           var f = document.forms[2].submit();
           f.submit();
    }
```

I have tried this:

```
var x, divArray = ["block1_b7", "block0_b7"];
for (x in divArray) {
        if (x) {
var searchString4 = "Incident",
  var  pageCon = document.getElementById(divArray[x]).innerHTML; 
}
```

I can't use jquery but I do have prototype 1.7.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have PrototypeJS available you can simplify lots of this javascript

PrototypeJS has a utility function `$()` which is the same as `document.getElementById()` but it will return a DOM element extended with all of the PrototypeJS functions. You can also pass more than one id to the `$()` function which will return an array of extended DOM elements.

Lets look at your first `<script>` block

```
window.onload = function() {
var searchString = "Incident",
    pageContent = document.getElementById("block1_b7").innerHTML;
var searchString2 = "Voice Services",
    pageContent = document.getElementById("block1_b7").innerHTML;
var searchString3 = "Data Service EVDO-1X & LTE",
    pageContent = document.getElementById("block1_b7").innerHTML;
if (pageContent.indexOf(searchString) != -1) 
   document.getElementById("areas").style.display = "inline";
if (pageContent.indexOf(searchString2) != -1) 
   document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display = "inline";
if (pageContent.indexOf(searchString3) != -1) 
   document.getElementById("dropdown2").style.display = "inline";
}
```

This can be reduced to the below. Be careful about the `show()` method, if styles farther up the chain have the element display set to 'none' then `show()` will have no effect. You can also use the second line as well to directly set the style.

```
window.onload = function() {
var searchStrings = ["Incident", "Voice Services", "Data Service EVDO-1X & LTE"];
searchStrings.each(function(str) {
    if($("block1_b7").innerHTML.include(str)) {
        $("block1_b7").show();
        //$("block1_b7").setStyle({display, "inline"});
    }
});
```

to use multiple ID's with the `$()` method

```
window.onload = function() {
var searchStrings = ["Incident", "Voice Services", "Data Service EVDO-1X & LTE"];
searchStrings.each(function(str) {
    $("block0_b7", "block1_b7").each(function(element) {
        if(element.innerHTML.include(str)) {
            element.show();
            //element.setStyle({display, "inline"});
        }
    }
});
```

If you have multiple ID's you want to check I would suggest putting a class on them ("searchblocks" below) so you can add more without updating the javascript code like so

```
searchStrings.each(function(str){
    $$(".searchblocks").each(function(element){
        if(element.innerHTML.include(str)){
            element.show();
            //element.setStyle({display:"inline"});
        }
    });
});
```

Looking at your second block

```
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
var mydropdown2 = document.getElementById('dropdown2');
var myareas = document.getElementById('areas');
mydropdown.onchange = function(){
    comment_body.value = comment_body.value + '\n' + this.value;
    var f = document.forms[2].submit();
    f.submit();
}
mydropdown2.onchange = function(){
    comment_body.value = comment_body.value + '\n' + this.value;
    var f = document.forms[2].submit();
    f.submit();
}
myareas.onchange = function(){ 
    comment_body.value = comment_body.value + '\n' + this.value;
    var f = document.forms[2].submit();
    f.submit();
}
```

Prototype adds excellent Event handling via the `observe()` or `on()` method - they are the same method just different names and it looks like all of the dropdowns are doing the same thing so we can add a class to all of them as well, for instance `selectblocks`

```
$$(".selectblocks").invoke("observe","change",function(){
    comment_body.value += '\n' + this.value;
    $$("form")[2].submit();
});
```

A little explanation `$$()` gets elements by CSS selector and will return an array of extended DOM elements.

`invoke()` will take an array and perform the same method on every item in the array, in this instance `observe()` and any parameters after the method name are passed to the method, in this instance the `function()` definition

you can simplify `comment_body.value = comment_body.value + '\n' + this.value;` to use the `+=` operator that adds or concats the right side to the left side.

`this` is still the element that the event is happening on

you can also access elements directly using `$$()` using the `[]` notation which allows you to access the 3rd form on the page and fire the `submit()`

Let me know if you have any questions and if anything doesn't make sense.